# Delete file with given extension

Tags: bash, shell

I want to remove files with extension that was given by a user. My problem is that it print "Not Found" and "rm: cannot remove ‘*.txt’"

```
echo Extension?
read ext

if [ -e *$ext ]
then 
    rm *$ext
else
    echo Not Found
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `-z` flag to check if the `$ext` variable is empty. The `-e` flag checks if a file exists.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Extension?
read ext

if [ ! -z $ext ]
then
    rm *.$ext
else
    echo Not Found
fi
```

I also added a `.` to the `rm` command. This reflects the desire to remove by extension. Otherwise, you'd be removing any file that ended with the user input (i.e. *program.c* and a file named *zodiac* would both be deleted).

Answer (score 0):

Use a bash array to ensure that white space is handled correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ask for ext until user enters one
ext=''
while [[ -z $ext ]]; do
    read -p 'Extension? ' ext
done

# find files
files=(*"$ext")
if [[ -e ${files[0]} )); then
    # delete files (-- prevents injection)
    rm -- "${files[@]}"
else
    # no files to delete
    echo "No files with extension: $ext"
fi
```